# Identify Devices On network

Tags: c#, sockets, network-programming

I am able to scan a IP range (say 192.168.0.1-192.168.0.255) for devices and get their MAC address and in some cases the Hostname. Below is the code to get host entry-

```
var host = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(ip));
```

**What I am not able to do is understand whether this device is a printer, a VOIP Phone, a camera, an android phone / apple phone or a computer and get the Model Name and the Manufacturer.** For computers / servers I can get the data - but then I have to treat each of the device as a computer and try to run discovery on them.

My requirement is to be able to identify during the range scan what kind of device it is and if possible get the Hostname, Model and Manufacturer. Thereafter I can decide how to proceed further with the device. I have been through numerous questions on stackoverflow and searched the net but am not able to get the answer.

One of the closest approximation i got was Network Discovery Service of Android. Unfortunately that does not work for me as I can trying to create a .NET application to run on windows. There are articles which say that MacID could be used to identify the manufacturer based on allocation. It  does not appeal to me at all. I cannot use third party network scanner software such as nmap (which does the work wonderfully)

Could you please guide me on what approach I need to take to get the Device Type and their hostname, model and manufacturer using freely available .NET assemblies / libraries OR if such a project has been tried before ... to link me to that. Thanks.

Comment: Even if you can't use `nmap` why not look at it and what it does to identify devices? It is open source after all.

Comment: See following : http://standards-oui.ieee.org/oui/oui.txt

Comment: The OUI can lead to finding the vendor or the network card/component at best. It could be misleading. For example, a server can use networking card from someone else. It does not at all tell what is the device Type - e.g.,Huawei could be a mobile, server or router.